# Matrix with uneven element lengths with added rows/columns

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

From the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484763/matrix-with-uneven-element-lengths)

Using the following code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, fit, matrix}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{matrix rows/.initial=5,matrix cols/.initial=6,matrix name/.initial=x,
vline/.style={/utils/exec=\foreach \XX in {1,...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix rows}}
{\ifnum\XX=1
\xdef\MatLstA{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-\XX-#1)}
\xdef\MatLstB{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-\XX-\the\numexpr1+#1\relax)}
\else
\xdef\MatLstA{\MatLstA (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-\XX-#1)}
\xdef\MatLstB{\MatLstB (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-\XX-\the\numexpr1+#1\relax)}
\fi},
insert path={node[fit=\MatLstA,inner sep=0pt] (fitA) {}
node[fit=\MatLstB,inner sep=0pt] (fitB) {}
($(fitA.east)!0.5!(fitB.west)$) coordinate (aux) 
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.north-|aux) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.south-|aux)}},%end vline
hline/.style={/utils/exec=\foreach \XX in {1,...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix cols}}
{\ifnum\XX=1
\xdef\MatLstA{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-#1-\XX)}
\xdef\MatLstB{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-\the\numexpr1+#1\relax-\XX)}
\else
\xdef\MatLstA{\MatLstA (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-#1-\XX)}
\xdef\MatLstB{\MatLstB (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-\the\numexpr1+#1\relax-\XX)}
\fi},insert path={node[fit=\MatLstA,inner sep=0pt] (fitA) {}
node[fit=\MatLstB,inner sep=0pt] (fitB) {}
($(fitA.south)!0.5!(fitB.north)$) coordinate (aux) 
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.west|-aux) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.east|-aux)}},%end hline
full matrix grid/.style={vline/.list={1,...,\the\numexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix cols}-1},
hline/.list={1,...,\the\numexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix rows}-1},
insert path={(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.south west) rectangle (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.north east)}}
}
\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (x) [matrix of nodes, row sep=10pt, column sep=10pt] {%
15.1 & 23.7 & 19.7 & 15.4 & 18.3 & 23.0 & y\\
17.4 & 18.6 & 12.9 & 20.320.320.3 & 13.7 & 21.45 & y\\
10.3 & 26.1 & 15.718.918.9 & 14.0 & 17.8 & 33.8 & y\\
23.2 & 12.9 & 29.8 & 18.3 & 14.2 & 20.8 & y\\
xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & y\\
13.5 & 17.1 & 20.7 & 27.1 & 18.918.9 & 16.6 & y\\};
\draw<2->[ultra thick, blue, latex'-] (x-2-1) node [fill, red!40!white, circle, inner sep=8pt, opacity=.4]{} -- (x-4-5) node [fill, blue!40!white, circle, inner sep=8pt, opacity=.4]{};
% Node names: (<name of matrix>-<row>-<column>)
% \draw[vline/.list={1,...,5},hline/.list={1,...,4}] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.north west) rectangle 
%  (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.south east); % 
\draw[matrix name=x,matrix cols=6,matrix rows=5,full matrix grid];% drawing the borders
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When new rows/columns are added, no lines are drawn between the new and previous ones. How can this be fixed?

I tried re-adjusting

```
matrix rows/.initial=5,matrix cols/.initial=6
```

to

```
matrix rows/.initial=0,matrix cols/.initial=0
```

or to

```
matrix rows/.initial=10,matrix cols/.initial=10
```

but it did not work.

From the answers I got, the problem was not on this line; the problem was that I did not re-adjust the line

`\draw[matrix name=x,matrix cols=6,matrix rows=5,full matrix grid];`

to

`\draw[matrix name=x,matrix cols=7,matrix rows=6,full matrix grid];`

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have to understand the code in the preamble. If you already understand, it will not be difficult.

Comment: @AndrewAs I said, I tried this, but it did not work

Comment: @JouleVMy programming knowledge is limited. Please if you have a solution to this problem tell me

Comment: Off topic: if you want to ping people, you must write e.g. `@Andrew As ...` instead of `@AndrewAs ...`.

Comment: @JouleV When I leave a space after the name, sometimes the name does not appear in the comment!

Comment: See there. You just pinged me. That means you succeeded.

Comment: @JouleV I tried re-adjusting

matrix rows/.initial=5,matrix cols/.initial=6
to

matrix rows/.initial=0,matrix cols/.initial=0
or to

matrix rows/.initial=10,matrix cols/.initial=10
but it did not work

Comment: Look at my answer and Andrew's answer. In short, you changed the initial values of `matrix rows`, `matrix cols`, but you reset these values later in your command, that is why it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the line:

```
\draw[matrix name=x,matrix cols=6,matrix rows=5,full matrix grid];
```

to

```
\draw[matrix name=x,matrix cols=7,matrix rows=6,full matrix grid];
```

All that this line is doing is drawing a grid with the specified number of rows and columns. In this case, this produces:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, fit, matrix}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{matrix rows/.initial=5,matrix cols/.initial=6,matrix name/.initial=x,
vline/.style={/utils/exec=\foreach \XX in {1,...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix rows}}
{\ifnum\XX=1
\xdef\MatLstA{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-\XX-#1)}
\xdef\MatLstB{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-\XX-\the\numexpr1+#1\relax)}
\else
\xdef\MatLstA{\MatLstA (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-\XX-#1)}
\xdef\MatLstB{\MatLstB (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-\XX-\the\numexpr1+#1\relax)}
\fi},
insert path={node[fit=\MatLstA,inner sep=0pt] (fitA) {}
node[fit=\MatLstB,inner sep=0pt] (fitB) {}
($(fitA.east)!0.5!(fitB.west)$) coordinate (aux)
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.north-|aux) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.south-|aux)}},%end vline
hline/.style={/utils/exec=\foreach \XX in {1,...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix cols}}
{\ifnum\XX=1
\xdef\MatLstA{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-#1-\XX)}
\xdef\MatLstB{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-\the\numexpr1+#1\relax-\XX)}
\else
\xdef\MatLstA{\MatLstA (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-#1-\XX)}
\xdef\MatLstB{\MatLstB (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-\the\numexpr1+#1\relax-\XX)}
\fi},insert path={node[fit=\MatLstA,inner sep=0pt] (fitA) {}
node[fit=\MatLstB,inner sep=0pt] (fitB) {}
($(fitA.south)!0.5!(fitB.north)$) coordinate (aux)
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.west|-aux) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.east|-aux)}},%end hline
full matrix grid/.style={vline/.list={1,...,\the\numexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix cols}-1},
hline/.list={1,...,\the\numexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix rows}-1},
insert path={(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.south west) rectangle (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.north east)}}
}
\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (x) [matrix of nodes, row sep=10pt, column sep=10pt] {%
15.1 & 23.7 & 19.7 & 15.4 & 18.3 & 23.0 & y\\
17.4 & 18.6 & 12.9 & 20.320.320.3 & 13.7 & 21.45 & y\\
10.3 & 26.1 & 15.718.918.9 & 14.0 & 17.8 & 33.8 & y\\
23.2 & 12.9 & 29.8 & 18.3 & 14.2 & 20.8 & y\\
xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & y\\
13.5 & 17.1 & 20.7 & 27.1 & 18.918.9 & 16.6 & y\\};
\draw<2->[ultra thick, blue, latex'-] (x-2-1) node [fill, red!40!white, circle, inner sep=8pt, opacity=.4]{} -- (x-4-5) node [fill, blue!40!white, circle, inner sep=8pt, opacity=.4]{};
% Node names: (<name of matrix>-<row>-<column>)
% \draw[vline/.list={1,...,5},hline/.list={1,...,4}] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.north west) rectangle
%  (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.south east); %
\draw[matrix name=x,matrix cols=7,matrix rows=6,full matrix grid];% drawing the borders
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Andrew has pointed out the right thing. Now let me dig into it. This is the `\tikzset`, aligned (in my favorite way)

```
\tikzset{
    matrix rows/.initial=5,
    matrix cols/.initial=6,
    matrix name/.initial=x,
    vline/.style={
        /utils/exec=\foreach \XX in {1,...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix rows}} {
            \ifnum\XX=1
                \xdef\MatLstA{
                    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-\XX-#1)}
                \xdef\MatLstB{
                    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-\XX-\the\numexpr1+#1\relax)}
            \else
                \xdef\MatLstA{
                    \MatLstA (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-\XX-#1)}
                \xdef\MatLstB{
                    \MatLstB (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-\XX-\the\numexpr1+#1\relax)}
            \fi},
        insert path={
            node[fit=\MatLstA,inner sep=0pt] (fitA) {}
            node[fit=\MatLstB,inner sep=0pt] (fitB) {} ($(fitA.east)!0.5!(fitB.west)$) coordinate (aux) 
            (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.north-|aux) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.south-|aux)}
    },%end vline
    hline/.style={
        /utils/exec=\foreach \XX in {1,...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix cols}} {
            \ifnum\XX=1
                \xdef\MatLstA{
                    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-#1-\XX)}
                \xdef\MatLstB{
                    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-\the\numexpr1+#1\relax-\XX)}
            \else
                \xdef\MatLstA{
                    \MatLstA (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-#1-\XX)}
                \xdef\MatLstB{
                    \MatLstB (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}-\the\numexpr1+#1\relax-\XX)}
            \fi},
        insert path={
            node[fit=\MatLstA,inner sep=0pt] (fitA) {}
            node[fit=\MatLstB,inner sep=0pt] (fitB) {} ($(fitA.south)!0.5!(fitB.north)$) coordinate (aux) 
            (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.west|-aux) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.east|-aux)}
    },%end hline
    full matrix grid/.style={
        vline/.list={1,...,\the\numexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix cols}-1},
        hline/.list={1,...,\the\numexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix rows}-1},
        insert path={(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.south west) rectangle (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.north east)}
    }
}
```

Without any knowledge in advance, I think we can still understand `vline` style will add vertical lines in a given list, and `hline` for horizontal lines.

Now, look at `full matrix grid`:

```
full matrix grid/.style={
    vline/.list={1,...,\the\numexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix cols}-1},
    hline/.list={1,...,\the\numexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix rows}-1},
    insert path={(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.south west) rectangle (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix name}.north east)}
}
```

It outputs a set of `hline`s and `vline`s, in a given list. The list is controled by `matrix cols` and `matrix rows` (`\the\numexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix cols}-1`, etc.), so you have to change the values of these options to change the grid.

The initial value of `matrix rows` and `matrix cols` are `5` and `6`, but that doesn't matter, because you already reset it again in the command

```
\draw[matrix name=x,matrix cols=6,matrix rows=5,full matrix grid];
```

Now, change the value of `matrix cols` and `matrix rows` in the above command, you will get what you want.

For the sake of completeness, see the compilable code in Andrew's answer.

Comment: Thank you all very much, I got it. and it works fine. By the way, I put @JouleV with a space after it, before Thank you, and it did not show

Comment: @Hany It is off topic here, but you can find out more how @ in comments work by reading [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/410270).

Comment: Thank you @JouleV