# TikZ matrix fails inside makebox or framebox

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix, ampersand

I want to draw a `framebox` around a TikZ picture.  But it won't compile.  I try `makebox` instead of `framebox`, but the problem persists.

Here is a MWE. `pdflatex` will raise `Undefined control sequence \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\makebox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes] { 
      text & text \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

---

Thanks for the answers.  They look as good but I can only accept one answer.

Problems with similar nature can be found here

- [tikz matrix undefined control sequence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208408/tikz-matrix-undefined-control-sequence)
- [Problem with defining shortcuts for TikZ matrices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/problem-with-defining-shortcuts-for-tikz-matrices) (Thanks [@js-bibra](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/197451/js-bibra))

The later explains why `&` causes the trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have three different solutions.

The first one uses `background` library to draw the `background rectangle` associated to any `tikzpicture`.

The second draw the `matrix` node without drawing inner matrix nodes. It's possible to use this solution because you draw a `matrix`.  With any other figure you should use previous solution.

And the third uses a `tcbox` (from `tcolorbox`). It's similar to `fbox` but with more configuration options. In this case you have to use `ampersand replacement` option into the matrix text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, backgrounds}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
    \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes] { 
      text & text \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%

  \begin{tikzpicture}%[show background rectangle]
    \matrix (m) [draw, matrix of nodes] { 
      text & text \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%

    \tcbox[sharp corners, colback=white, size=fbox]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&] { 
      text \& text \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found option `ampersand replacement=\&` (as follows) will solve the problem.

```tex
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&] { 
  text \& text \\
};
```

Though I would still appreciate if someone can explain why `&` causes troubles insides `\makebox`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1113/197451 -- explanation

Comment: @jsbibra Thanks for pointing the link.  I hope I could accept this comment as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,fit}

\begin{document}
%   \makebox{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes] { 
                text & text \\
            };
        \node[draw,fit=(m-1-1) (m-1-2),inner sep=0pt]{};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
%   }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `ampersand replacement`, you have also the following workaround: compose in a box and, then put the box as argument of your command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\setbox1=\hbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes] { 
      text & text \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\fbox{\box1}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 2):

From TikZ & PGF manual (v 3.1.8b, page 321) is noted:

> 4. If you place a matrix on a path, the matrix contents will be collected into a macro, which tokenizes them. This means that & will
>    lose its meaning as an alignment character, resulting in an error. If
>    you need to place a matrix on a path, use ampersand replacement to
>    work around that problem.

So, inserting `tikzpicture` in frame is such a case.

It is not clear, what is intention of your frame around `tikzpicture`. If you like to have frame only around matrix, than you can simply write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             draw] % <---
{
text & text \\
};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case, that frame is around more complex image content, than you can use `fit` library and solve your problem on the following way:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,
                matrix,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m1) [matrix of nodes,
              draw]
{
first & matrix \\
};
\matrix (m2) [matrix of nodes,
              draw,
              right=of m1]
{
second      & matrix \\
left cell   & right cell \\
};
\draw[->]   (m1) -- (m2);
\node[draw=red, fit=(current bounding box)]{}; % <---
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]